# set value on select with setValue() in angular

Tags: angular

I have the next select options in angular:

```
<select
     class="form-control form-control-sm"
     id="StatusTask"
     formControlName="StatusTask"
     name="StatusTask"
    >
    <option value="new" [selected]="true">New</option>
    <option value="inprocess">In process</option>
    <option value="solved">Solved</option>
    <option value="end">end</option>
</select>
```

for set the value I'm using the next:

```
var MyInfo = "new";
this.formEditTask.get('StatusTask').setValue(MyInfo);
```

But it is not working, I need set the option where the label contains the same value I'm giving to it,so how can I do it?

Comment: what version of angular you are using?

Comment: @MadhuNair is version (9.1.12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `[(ngModel)]` to change the value.
2. Add `FormsModule` into module.ts file

check the solution
i have created a stackblitz for you .let me know if you have any problem viewing it

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-fqw2qm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  <select
     class="form-control form-control-sm"
     id="StatusTask"
     formControlName="StatusTask"
     name="StatusTask"
   >
  <option ngValue="new">New</option>
  <option ngValue="inprocess">In process</option>
  <option ngValue="solved">Solved</option>
  <option ngValue="end">end</option>
</select>
```

with ngValue angular should correctly read the value